# ERROR SitecoreConnectionManager: with ERROR Internal Server Error. Failed to logging

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I reinstalled Commerce, everything works fine. I created a new catalog. After few hours I was not able to open Bussiness Tools and I have next errors on logs:

> 21:20:01 INFO Management.GetCommerceTerms./sitecore/Commerce/Commerce
>   Control Panel/Commerce Engine Settings/Commerce Terms/System
>   Messages|en 48 21:20:01 INFO Successfully validated the token. 48
>   21:20:01 INFO AuthenticationScheme:
>   "BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt" was successfully
>   authenticated. 48 21:20:01 INFO AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was
>   successfully authenticated. 48 21:20:01 INFO Authorization was
>   successful for user: "sitecore\Admin". 49 21:20:01 ERROR
>   SitecoreConnectionManager: RETRY 2 out of 3 with ERROR Internal Server
>   Error. Failed to logging. /sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login for GET
>   /sitecore/api/ssc/item/?path=%2Fsitecore%2FCommerce%2FCommerce%20Control%20Panel%2FCommerce%20Engine%20Settings%2FCommerce%20Terms%2FSystem%20Messages&database=master&language=en
>   57 21:20:01 INFO
>   Management.block.getitembypath./sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control
>   Panel/Storefront
>   Settings/Storefronts/CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront|en 57 21:20:01
>   INFO Management.block.getitembypath./sitecore/Commerce/Commerce
>   Control Panel/Storefront
>   Settings/Storefronts/CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront: Language=en 49
>   21:20:01 ERROR SitecoreConnectionManager: RETRY 3 out of 3 with ERROR
>   Internal Server Error. Failed to logging. /sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login
>   for GET
>   /sitecore/api/ssc/item/?path=%2Fsitecore%2FCommerce%2FCommerce%20Control%20Panel%2FCommerce%20Engine%20Settings%2FCommerce%20Terms%2FSystem%20Messages&database=master&language=en
>   49 21:20:01 ERROR SitecoreConnectionManager.Error: Message=RETRY
>   FAILED for GET
>   /sitecore/api/ssc/item/?path=%2Fsitecore%2FCommerce%2FCommerce%20Control%20Panel%2FCommerce%20Engine%20Settings%2FCommerce%20Terms%2FSystem%20Messages&database=master&language=en|Trace=
>   at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionManager.ProcessRequest(CommerceContext
>   commerceContext, String action, String method, ItemModel itemModel)
>   System.Exception: RETRY FAILED for GET
>   /sitecore/api/ssc/item/?path=%2Fsitecore%2FCommerce%2FCommerce%20Control%20Panel%2FCommerce%20Engine%20Settings%2FCommerce%20Terms%2FSystem%20Messages&database=master&language=en
>   at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionManager.ProcessRequest(CommerceContext
>   commerceContext, String action, String method, ItemModel itemModel)

On browser I also have errors:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
>   main.564e7ed772d982491157.bundle.js:1 Http failure response for
>   https://commerce-authoring.x.local/api/GetNavigationView(): 400 OK
>   n.handleError @ main.564e7ed772d982491157.bundle.js:1
>   vendor.d6cd11b36eec3f38b8a2.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in
>   promise): Http failure response for
>   https://commerce-authoring.x.local/api/GetNavigationView(): 400 OK
>       at new V (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at N (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at N (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.d6cd11b36eec3f38b8a2.bundle.js:1)
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at n.runTask (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at _ (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)

**Update**

Some custom code is causing this issue. Is Sitecore code not Commmerce code. I added a ProductCatalogItemResolver and looks like is crashing the code. I revert back the code and I still have have the same issue. Looks like my HabitatAuthoring environment was corupted but I don't understand how is possible because I am not modifying anything into commerce.

Comment: This might be too obvious, but from the log it seems Commerce Engine cannot connect to Sitecore XP. Did you check your contentpolicy file to see if the url's and login are correct?

Comment: Hi Erwin, the issue is caused by some custom code. I will update the question because is not clear why is crashing.

Comment: it looks like Sitecore is responding with a 500.. is there anything in the Sitecore logs that would give you more information on the error?